# how to convert spring boot websocket text message to custom java object (bean or DTO) in webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-websocket

i am creating  websocket application, and i want to get a custom object from the server side and convert into my custom java object. i am using reactive websocket for my project.

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

     session.receive()
             .map(webSocketMessage -> {
                 //i want to convert the  webSocketMessage into my object here to set properties   
                 MyObject object = new MyObject();
                 //object.setName()
                 //object.setAddress()
                 return object;
             }).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: You have to convert `webSocketMessage.payload` to your DTO. Edit your question providing sample data that you are expecting to receive,

Comment: i want to convert ```webSocketMessage``` into ```MyObject``` that's all. i want to get name and address from the webSocketMessage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't want to use text the message. instead of using the text message you can get byte array from the `webSocketMessage` `webSocketMessage.getPayload().asInputStream().readAllBytes()` and after that, you can use `ObjectMapper` to convert byte[] to the object like below. after that you can continue the pipeline as you want. make sure to use `handle` to identify the whatever error with the ObjectMapper.

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

    session.receive()
            .handle((webSocketMessage, synchronousSink) -> {
                try {
                    MyObject myObject = new ObjectMapper()
                            .readValue(
                                    webSocketMessage.getPayload().asInputStream().readAllBytes(),
                                    MyObject.class
                            );
                    synchronousSink.next(myObject);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    synchronousSink.error(e);
                }
            })
            .cast(MyObject.class)
            .subscribe();

}
```

Comment: why we use ```cast``` here?

Comment: because the handle function will return you an object type. because he doesn't what kind of object you will pass as next. therefore, you need to cast the exact object that you pass.